# afterimage when reloading tableview section in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, cell

Hello i'm trying to make drop down menu using `tableview` and its `cells`

I use default `tableview` `cell` for menu and custom cell for content

custom cell has `CollectionView` and `CollectionView` has its `cells`

drop down and up works fine but it has afterimages like this

[image]

this is my code for when menu title cell (default cell) selected

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            sectionDatas[indexPath.section].isOpended = sectionDatas[indexPath.section].isOpended ? false : true
            let sections = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
    }
```

is there any solution to remove that afterimages

Comment: what you try to do here? please explain. i didn't get your problem which you faced here.

Comment: try to add empty section footer to your section.

Comment: @RatneshJain Still same issue.

Comment: I solved this problem by animation block and its completion block 
This is my source code https://github.com/ehdrjsdlzzzz/tistory-ios/tree/master/ExpandingTableView

Answer (score 0):

Try to set clipToBounds = true for collection view or IsHidden - true/false(for collection view)

Comment: thanks! but clipToBounds and masksToBounds not work,
and i tried isHidden but it didn't work too.
where should i write isHidden code?
cellforRowAt?